# Running Selenium tests with Xamarin Studion on MAC

Tags: macos, selenium-webdriver, mono, xamarin-studio

I am trying to run my created tests on `Visual Studio 2010`, using `Selenium WebDriver`, in a MAC using Xamarin Studio. I have `chromedriver.exe` as EmbeddedResource, so I removed and add the one for mac (chromedriver).

Everything looks okay but doesnt allow me to run them because I see this error:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : Unexpected error. System.Net.WebException: Error: ConnectFailure (Connection refused) ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Connection refused
 at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect (System.Net.EndPoint remoteEP) [0x000f1] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-3.12.0-branch-32/bockbuild-mono-3.12.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-3.12.0/mcs/class/System/System.Net.Sockets/Socket_2_1.cs:1257 
 at System.Net.WebConnection.Connect (System.Net.HttpWebRequest request) [0x0019b] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-3.12.0-branch-32/bockbuild-mono-3.12.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-3.12.0/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebConnection.cs:213 
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
 at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00045] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-3.12.0-branch-32/bockbuild-mono-3.12.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-3.12.0/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpWebRequest.cs:849 
 at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream () [0x00057] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-3.12.0-branch-32/bockbuild-mono-3.12.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-3.12.0/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpWebRequest.cs:865 
 at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute (OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.Command commandToExecute) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
 at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute (OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.Command commandToExecute) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
 at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute (System.String driverCommandToExecute, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2 parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Any idea what is going on? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @ElBandidoCan you please disable firewall and check again please chek my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28539625/attempting-to-run-multiple-selenium-webdriver-tests-using-nunit-fails/28551171#28551171

Comment: Yeap its already disable, not working

Comment: I am running into the same issue. Did you ever find a solution?